# what is the maximum limit of the grid we can draw with webgl

Tags: canvas, webgl

Currently, I'm working on a project where I need to draw a grid with the size of N * N.
here N can be of a size 998.I've successfully drawn the matrix of dimension 108 * 108. But when I tried to draw with size 216 * 216 it shows only half of the matrix. The result can be seen in the given image

I tried to debug but I'm pretty sure everything is correct in my code.

Here is my implementation.

https://github.com/knakul853/tvb-framework/blob/master/tvb/interfaces/web/templates/genshi/visualizers/connectivity/scripts/myconnectivityMatrix.js

I want to know that is there any limit for the drawing. if there is a limit can anyone explain a bit about it?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not entirely read your code, but I had similar problems when I used `Uint16Array` for storing indices. Meaning that the amount of vertices you are using, will need you to use a 32 bit indices buffer.

Try changing your code to:

```
var indices = new Uint32Array(nrElems * nrElems * 2 * 3);
var linesIndices = new Uint32Array(nrElems * nrElems * 2 * 4);
```

Also for your `gl.drawElements` call use `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` instead of `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

According to gman's comment you also have to to check for an enable the [OES_element_index_uint](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/) extension, otherwise you'll get an error

You also might be interested in this [answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/8043/7457)

Comment: If you're going to use `UNSIGNED_INT` with `gl.drawElements` you need to check for an enable the [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/) extension, otherwise you'll get an error

Comment: @indexoutofbounds  have some other problem, I need to draw a matrix 998 X 998. but when I draw it shows like this https://imgur.com/j80aAu8  do you have any idea how can we get rid of this.